# $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x+3){x^{-2}} \mathrm d x}$ converges?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I ran into this question:

show convergence/divergence of:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x+3){x^{-2}} \mathrm d x}$$

I tried for a long time and I'm kind'a lost.
according to the answer, it should diverge.

Thanks in advance,

yaron.

Comment: There are two edge cases that may be problematic. You probably concentrated on the wrong one.

Comment: @Daniel actually, i separated to the cases 0->1 and the case 1->infinity

Comment: At $0$, you have a pole of order 2, that isn't integrable.

Comment: Note, for $0< x\le 1$, $  \ln(x+3)x^{-2}\ge x^{-2}>0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra and what does that tell me?

Comment: Use a Comparison test. $\int_0^1 x^{-2}\,dx$ diverges; thus, $\int_0^1\ln(x+3)x^{-2}\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: @DavidMitra my question is why $\int_{0}^{1}{{x^{-2}} \mathrm d x}$ diverges.

Comment: Just evaluate: $\int_a^1 x^{-2}\,dx= -x^{-1}\bigl|_a^1\ ={1\over a}-1\ \buildrel{a\rightarrow 0^+}\over\longrightarrow\ \infty $.

Comment: @DavidMitra got it. thank you very much. i guess because i got to caught on to the convergence tests, i forget to simply evaluate.

Comment: You're welcome. (Incidentally, you could have calculated $\int_a^1 \ln(x+3)x^{-2}\,dx$ directly using integration by parts. This would be a bit tedious, though...)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=\ln{x}+3$.

$\displaystyle \int_{3}^{\infty} ue^{2(3-u)}e^{u-3}\mathrm{d}u=\int_{3}^{\infty} ue^{3-u}\mathrm{d}u=\left[ -ue^{3-u}-e^{3-u}\right]_3^{\infty}$ which diverges for $u=3$.

P.S. Happy $\tau$ day!

Comment: The integral $\int_3^\infty u\exp(3-u) du $ converge and his value is 4. There is no divergence in u=3.